# Переход по ссылкам одной страницы

Tags: python, html

Есть сайт https://page.kakao.com/main. Он одностраничный, вернее работает на технологии подгрузки контента без обновления страницы.
Скрипт должен работать так:

1. Заходим на https://page.kakao.com/main
2. Переходим на https://page.kakao.com/new/today?categoryUid=10
3. Получаем код html страницы

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать на Python, НЕ используя Selenium.
*Если просто попробовать вставить вторую ссылку в поиск, оно перебрасывает на начальную страницу.

Нужно получить эти данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если тебе список получить, то его можно получить по [ссылке](https://api2-page.kakao.com/api/v2/store/day_of_week_top/list?category=10&subcategory=0&page=1&day=7&bm=A)

там json объект который без труда можно распарсить

в этом запросе есть параметр page=1 его меняешь(page=2, &page=3 и тд) и получаешь еще данные

вот пример что получаем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может я вас не понял но, на https://page.kakao.com/new/today?categoryUid=10 подгружается div class= jsx-3101720335 mainContents mainContents_pc  hiddenMenuContent. Мне нужно как то получить его содержимое. Но проблема в том что сразу перейти на эту страницу нельзя, при прямом переходе на неё меня перебрасывает на начальную страницу на которой не этот див, там div class jsx-1917992880 mainContents mainContents_pc.

Comment: так в json'е есть все это!

Comment: Извиняюсь за свою глупость, но я до сих пор не понимаю как мне найти вот эту часть ссылки /home?seriesId=55803708. Я перебрал наверное все страницы этого json'а и ничего не нашел.

Comment: https://api2-page.kakao.com/api/v2/store/today_new?category=10&subcategory=0

Comment: Все понял, хороший ответ!